# How do I enable 'scroll with mouse cursor' on mac? (not sure of exact name)

Tags: mac, touchpad, scrolling

I'm not sure what to call it, but sometimes when using a fancy mouse I accidentally enter this mode where there's an icon in the center of the screen that looks a bit like a compass and then when I just move my mouse cursor up or down it has the effect of scrolling up or down.

How can I set up a shortcut for this on my Mac?

Effectively I just want to be able to scroll with one finger (thumb) rather than two. (For ergonomic reasons.)

Thanks!

Comment: You have to go to System Preferences > Mouse and enable the setting there if my memory doesn't betray me. You can even enable right click. I don't have a apple mouse with me so I can't verify if it works or not.

Comment: Define 'fancy mouse' & also what OS you've seen this feature in.